# What does "light" mean here?

Tags: meaning

> She is now two minutes behind schedule, but she can make that up if
> she cuts through the minimall instead of waiting for the **light**.

Does it mean the traffic lights?

light or lights?

*[Hadley and Grace](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082WW397G)* by Suzanne Redfearn

Comment: That interpretation makes sense in this context. (Presumably it should be _instead of_?)

Comment: yes I edited it.

Comment: In Britain, we would refer to the *lights* for traffic lights.  We can guess this is an American author because of the singular.

Answer (score 1):

It should probably be "mini-mall", "mini mall", or capitalized "Mini Mall" for an official name such as "Fort Benning Main Post Exchange Mini Mall."

"instead of waiting for the light" refers to a red traffic light.